# How to pass dictionary parameter to web-api method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've read all similar questions here, but i can't come up with solution. I'm trying to call web-api method:

```
[HttpGet]
public SearchViewModel Get(SearchTypes type, string text, [FromUri]Dictionary<string, string> toyParams)
{
    //Code here
}
```

and i want to get last parameter from uri. I've tried

> http://localhost:39101/#!/search/toys/fox?someParameter=123

and

> http://localhost:39101/#!/search/toys/fox?toyParams[0].Key=someParameter&toyParams[0].Value=123

but toyParams `Dictionary` always empty.

Comment: What if you comma separate the values in the URL, get them back as a long string, then split them to get the toyParams.

Comment: Seems like a hack, not a solution.)

Comment: passing dictionary key/values via URI in a GET request!!. Why don't you have some kind of id for the data you want to retrieve, so that you don't have to pass such huge data in URI

Comment: I had assumed you wanted to conform to GET request semantics. Otherwise if its a general solution considering you are passing quite some data, then you may need to do a good old POST request will have to do.

Comment: i don't think you will be able to do that. Reason being, web api model default model binding work with name comparison. for example if you have a parameter named "toyParams[0].Key" (although you can't have it.) that will map with the query string parameter"toyParams[0],Key" having a value "someParameter" and so on. You might be able to do it via a custom model binding. BUT, please don't do it this way. I will wait for an answer to arrive to update my knowledge.

Comment: @singsuyash I'm trying to organize search by params and in some usecases it'll be great if user could share link to search results.

Comment: this talks about a POST request, and the data is being sent as a post body not via url.

Comment: i am thinking about your search by params problem. you must have your search params like param1=value1&param2=value2 and so on right? Now you can create a class (DTO, Data Transfer Object) that contains properties i.e. param1, param2 with their respective dataTypes. it will fill up!  Would you like this approach as an answer?

Comment: @singsuyash I've tried to do common method, smth like "search object by params"... If it's difficult, i'll do a few methods by object types.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out it is implicitly answered at another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457149/how-to-bind-a-dictionary-from-url-query-based-on-parameter-name-prefix).

The solution it points at redirects to [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dictionaries).

Or, short answer, you just compose your request like so:

> http://localhost:39101/#!/search/toys/fox?toyParams[someParameter1]=123&toyParams[someParameter2]=456

Answer (score 0):

API Method accepting dictionary as the request object.

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<IActionResult> TestDictionary(Dictionary<string, List<MyList>> pairs)
{
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        var a = new 
        { 
             Id = pair.Key, 
             Name = pair.Value.FirstOrDefault().Name,
             Age = pair.Value.FirstOrDefault().Age
        };
        return Ok(a);
    }
    return NotFound();
}

class MyList
{
    string Name { get; set; };
    string Age { get; set; };
}
```

Request object for testing the API.

```
{
  "myid": [
    {
      "Name": "testName",
      "Age": "testAge"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response received.

```
{
  "Id": "myid",
  "Name": "testName",
  "Age": "testAge"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even though its quite late but following method is available to return query parameters as a name/value pair - 
this.Url.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()

I have following Url -
http://localhost:49980/api/MyRestAPI/postSomeData/?a=v&d=e

Following is my method, written in Web API 2 -

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveDataFromRestToDB(string dataKey) {
     var parameters = this.Url.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
     //parameters returns KeyValuePair<string, string>[2], containing values passed in Url Query
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -4):

One Simple way, instead of dictionary:

```
    //DTO
    public class SearchDTO
    {
        public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Where `MyProperty1`, `MyProperty2`, `MyProperty3` are the params based on which something has to be searched.

```
        //GET Method
        public string Get([FromUri]SearchDTO searchDTO)
        {
            return "search result";
        }
```

Below is the Calling URL :

http://localhost:56880/api/values?myproperty1=1&myproperty2=2&myproperty3=3

Comment: old answer but this is not a good solution, in a context that u have to pass multiple dynamics parameters this solution is invalid.

Comment: What other way is available in case of a GET request?

Comment: I would really like to know "What other way is available in case of a GET request?" Downvoters, can you please explain( i want to know because i want to learn something)