# How to bind a Dictionary from URL query, based on parameter name prefix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I need to handle `http://host.my/path?normal=1&othernormal=2&dict_a=b&dict_x=y`

Here's my latest attempt at it, based off [How to use Bind Prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317523/how-to-use-bind-prefix) :

```
public string Get(int normal, int othernormal,
    [Bind(Prefix="dict_")]
    Dictionary<string, string> dict) { ... }
```

That creates a dictionary, however, it is empty.

It is important to note, that `dict_a`, and `dict_x` are not known in advance. E.g. `dict_abracadabra=bla` must be allowed.

Comment: You would need the url to be `...&dict[0].Key=b&dict[0].Value=y` to bind to your parameter (without the `[Bind(Prefix="dit_")]` Why not just parameters `string dict_a, string dict_x` and create the dictionary from the values?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, because I do not control the client. My question actually has the answer to your second question.

Comment: The you going to need to just read the values from the query string (or create a custom model binder to do it) and create the dictionary from the values.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to bind these values to a dictionary without a bind prefix.  A dictionary will consume any simple values in the querystring.

Your sample query and method signature (without the bind prefix), and it seems to work *pretty much* as expected:
[image: debugger]

I've tested this in MVC 1.1.0-preview1-final.

From the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding